# changing char by subtracting its ASCII code in c language

Tags: c, ascii

I am doing some string workshop for my c learning. There is a problem, where you ask for a user input let say "bob" and the code is to lower its ASCII code so it becomes "ana". I am at loss on how I go about doing this. Would it be something like

```
int main() {
    char str[10];
    char test[10];
    int i;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    while(str[i]!='\0') {
       test[i]=str[i]; i++;
    }
}
```

If I were to print this it only gives me the ASCII code and not the letters associated with it. How would I take the ASCII code and turn it into letters? Or is there a better method for it

Comment: You have no `a[]` in the variable declarations. Please [edit] and post your **real code** that compiles. Also, why have you made `str` an array of `char`, but `test` an array of `int`?

Comment: `i` is uninitialised. And you have not terminated the `test` array (assuming your real code prints it).

Comment: "If I were to print this it only gives me the ASCII code and not the letters associated with it." Please show us exactly how you are printing. Also show a run with both input and output examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
test[i] = orig[i] - 1;
```

> If I were to print this it only gives me the ASCII code

That just means you are not printing it correctly. This should work:

```
printf("orig: %s, transformed: %s\n", orig, test);
```

Comment: thank you, also from help of the post under, I don't need to worry about the whole conversion thing.

Answer (score 1):

In C, `char` is an integer type. There's no need to convert between a code and a letter: the letter is the code. For example, on ASCII systems `'a' == 97`.

In other words, you can simply do `str[i]--;` directly (assuming your platform uses ASCII).

Comment: Thank you, didn't know you did not have to worry about converting and what not, helped out greatly